# How to insert figure inside tcolorbox environment before the \begin{document}

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, includegraphics, resize

In order to insert a logo picture in my sheet, I want to use the tcolorbox, but I don't know how to create a new environment to include it inside a node before the \begin{document}.

Here's my code that can be compile correctly with xelatex

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} \usepackage[top=13cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry} \usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage{tikz,varwidth,multicol}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\pagestyle{empty} 
\definecolor{fff}{RGB}{249, 212, 6} 
\definecolor{vvv}{RGB}{47, 138, 58}
\definecolor{ccc}{RGB}{255,140,0} 
\definecolor{ggg}{RGB}{250,250,250} 
\tikzset{a/.style={anchor=west,line width=1.5pt,font=\bfseries\Large,rounded corners=2mm,draw=black,text=black,inner xsep=5mm,minimum height=1.5cm,rotate=-90}} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\image}[3][1]{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth,height=#2\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#3}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(1.base)] \node[circle,fill=fff,text=black,font=\bfseries,minimum size=5mm,inner sep=0mm](1){\arabic{enumi}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} } 
\AddToShipoutPicture{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [fill=fff,minimum width=\paperheight,minimum height=2cm,anchor=south east,rotate=-90](0)at ([xshift=0cm]current page.south west){}; 
\node[a](2)at($(0.west)!.9!(0.east)$){\image[0.1]{0.9}{./images/logo}
}; 
 
\end{tikzpicture} }
%---- define the border of exercice ------%
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{exo}{breakable,top=1cm,title={Exercice \thetcbcounter},enhanced,before skip=5mm,after skip=5mm,boxsep=3mm,coltitle=black,attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight},boxrule=.5pt,boxed title style={interior empty,frame code={ \fill([xshift=1mm]frame.north east)arc(180:0:1mm)([xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)arc(0:180:1mm); \path[right color=fff,left color=fff,middle color=fff!60] ([shift={(-.2,.1)}]frame.north west)--([shift={(.2,.1)}]frame.north east)[rounded corners=1mm]--([xshift=.1cm]frame.north east)--(frame.south east)--(frame.south west)--([xshift=-.1cm]frame.north west)[sharp corners]--cycle; } }}\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french} 
\newfontfamily\frenchfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\vspace{15cm}
\begin{exo} 
Recopier et compléter les égalités suivantes:
\begin{enumerate} 
\item $7\times15-\cdots )=70$ 
\item $5\times13-5\times\cdots =50$
\item $17\times(3.4+\cdots)=170$
\item $23\times2.3+23\times\cdots=230$
\end{enumerate}
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.13\textheight,
    enhanced,clip upper,%<------------
    colframe=red,colback=gray,boxrule=1pt,arc=10pt,
    boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt]
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.13\textheight]{./images/logo}
\end{tcolorbox} \end{center}
\end{exo} 

\end{document}
```

when I compile this code, I get the following document  [image: fix fill size image in margin]
Ccan anyone help remove the badding (the white space) of the picture in the left margin?
It would be very appreciated.

Comment: Mmm… It's not quite clear to me. Do you really wishing to  insert a \tcolorbox with the logo in the margin, or do you think a \tcolorbox is necessary to insert the logo?

Comment: Or is your complaint that the image you've inserted has a white background instead of yellow?

Comment: just, i want to remove the white space in the image, i can do this inside the document environment but in the margin i don't khnow how isert it ?

Comment: I don't see how you remove white space in the image inside the document.  I would assume that you have a white background because `imges/logo` has a white background.  Can you make the background transparent?

Comment: I want to make the image with full size in border , you can see the difference between the two images the image that i had insert using the tcolorbox has no badding but that i insert with the newcommand in the margin has a badding (sapce between the image and border)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this. I've defined a `myboxedlogo` command with three parameters: Optional tcolorbox parameters, includegraphics parameters and figure name. This command is used to include the logo in main page and on left margin.

By the way, instead of a `tcolorbox` I've used a `tcbincludegraphics` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} \usepackage[top=13cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage{tikz,varwidth,multicol}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\pagestyle{empty} 
\definecolor{fff}{RGB}{249, 212, 6} 
\definecolor{vvv}{RGB}{47, 138, 58}
\definecolor{ccc}{RGB}{255,140,0} 
\definecolor{ggg}{RGB}{250,250,250} 

\tikzset{a/.style={inner sep=0pt}} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\image}[3][1]{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth,height=#2\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#3}}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(1.base)] \node[circle,fill=fff,text=black,font=\bfseries,minimum size=5mm,inner sep=0mm](1){\arabic{enumi}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} } 

\newcommand{\myboxedlogo}[3][]{%
\tcbincludegraphics[hbox, size=tight, colframe=red, boxrule=1pt, arc=10pt, auto outer arc, clip upper, #1, graphics options={#2}]{#3}
}

\AddToShipoutPicture{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [fill=fff,minimum width=\paperheight,minimum height=2cm,anchor=south east,rotate=-90](0)at ([xshift=0cm]current page.south west){}; 
\node[inner sep=0pt](2)at($(0.west)!.9!(0.east)$){\myboxedlogo{width=.1\textwidth, height=0.9\textheight, keepaspectratio, angle=-90}{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture} }

%---- define the border of exercice ------%
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{exo}{breakable,top=1cm,title={Exercice \thetcbcounter},enhanced,before skip=5mm,after skip=5mm,boxsep=3mm,coltitle=black,attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight},boxrule=.5pt,boxed title style={interior empty,frame code={ \fill([xshift=1mm]frame.north east)arc(180:0:1mm)([xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)arc(0:180:1mm); \path[right color=fff,left color=fff,middle color=fff!60] ([shift={(-.2,.1)}]frame.north west)--([shift={(.2,.1)}]frame.north east)[rounded corners=1mm]--([xshift=.1cm]frame.north east)--(frame.south east)--(frame.south west)--([xshift=-.1cm]frame.north west)[sharp corners]--cycle; } }}\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french} 
\newfontfamily\frenchfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\vspace{15cm}
\begin{exo} 
Recopier et compléter les égalités suivantes:
\begin{enumerate} 
\item $7\times15-\cdots )=70$ 
\item $5\times13-5\times\cdots =50$
\item $17\times(3.4+\cdots)=170$
\item $23\times2.3+23\times\cdots=230$
\end{enumerate}
\begin{center}
%\begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.13\textheight,
%    enhanced,clip upper,%<------------
%    colframe=red,colback=gray,boxrule=1pt,arc=10pt,
%    boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt]
%     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.13\textheight]{example-image-a}
%\end{tcolorbox} 
\myboxedlogo[colframe=blue]{width=.3\textwidth, height=0.13\textheight}{example-image-a}
\end{center}
\end{exo} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help in solving this problem.